# Azure functions v3 attach debugger to docker container in local started with docker-compose (dotnet)

Tags: c#, .net, docker-compose, azure-functions

I`m trying to incorporate the azure function (c#) in the already existing docker-compose file. By reverse engineering from how visual studio starting container and build image, I have ended up with something like this:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
    azure.storage.emulator:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite:latest"        
        container_name: azure.storage.emulator
        ports:
            - 10000:10000
            - 10001:10001
        volumes: 
            - azurite_data:/data mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
        networks: 
            - internal_network 
    azure.function:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: FunctionApp/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - 'C:\Users\MyComputer\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw'
            - 'C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\docker infrastructure\TestFunction\FunctionApp\FunctionApp:/home/site/wwwroot'
            - 'C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\docker infrastructure\TestFunction\FunctionApp:/src/'
            - 'C:\Users\MyComputer\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Containers_2109029\Releases\3.20.0\linuxCLI:/functions_debugging_cli:ro'
            - 'C:\Users\MyComputer\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2'
            - 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages'    
        ports:
            - 8081:80
        container_name: Azure.Function
        networks: 
            - internal_network
        entrypoint:
            - tail
        command:
            - -f
            - /dev/null    
        depends_on:
            - azure.storage.emulator
        environment:
            - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
            - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:10123
            - NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2
            - NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2
            - WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT=1,
            - FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME=dotnet
            - AzureWebJobsStorage=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://azure.storage.emulator:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://azure.storage.emulator:10001/devstoreaccount1;

# NETWORKS
networks:
  internal_network:

# VOLUMES
volumes:
  azurite_data:
```

Hitting localhost/8081 I can verify that function is running, but I can not confirm that it does its job.

**Another big problem** is that when I attach to function with a remote debugger I can not debug it, because symbols are not loaded.

I would really appreciate it if anybody can help me with running and debugging the Azure function started through a docker-compose file.
There are several articles on the web, but I haven't had luck with the steps described in them.

my docker file looks like this:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0-appservice AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FunctionApp/FunctionApp.csproj", "FunctionApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FunctionApp/FunctionApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FunctionApp"
RUN dotnet build "FunctionApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FunctionApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

**To summarize, I`m asking for help with starting and debugging azure functions v3 started by docker-compose**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have ended up with a custom image. It works fine in the local environment and debugger can be attached to it, but I`m not sure if suitable to deploy image to azure, probably not.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | /bin/sh /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FunctionApp/FunctionApp.csproj", "FunctionApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FunctionApp/FunctionApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FunctionApp"
ENTRYPOINT ["func","host","start","--verbose"]
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I believe you'll have to do the profiling. You will have to follow these:

1. If its not a blessed image, then first you would have to install SSH if you want to get into the container.
2. Then you will have to make use of tools such as cProfile or other related python modules to profile the code.

Here is a documentation for windows application. You might want to take a look : https://azureossd.github.io/2017/09/01/profile-python-applications-in-azure-app-services/index.html

This issue has been tracked : https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/issues/17

Comment: Thank you for your answer, altho in my case, it is dotnet function.
I`m using mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0-appservice as a base.
Do you have any suggestions in that case?
I have created custom image, it is good for dev but i`m not sure if it is suitable for deploy on azure.

Comment: @Nikola - for production its best to use the actual azure functions instances.  Not the emulator deployed to a "production" box.